# (SOLVED) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') and TypeError: TestContract.name is not a function

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, web3-providers

This is my simple js code (without api). I try to do my first steps with js and web3 and the goal is to fetch data from the OMG network, a very simple task, but for some reason it is not working. I tried to do some variations like with brackets with the methods.name eg.
I am getting the following errors:

> TypeError: TestContract.name is not a function

and

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')

the Code:

```
const { Web3 } = require('web3'); 

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/fa26d14d8e984def8d480be40582be12"));
const address = "0xd26114cd6EE289AccF82350c8d8487fedB8A0C07"
const abi = [
 ...
]

const TestContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);

async function getTokenName() {
    let tokenName = await TestContract.name().call();
    console.log(tokenName)
}

getTokenName()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to web3js v1.2.11

```
let tokenName = await tokenName.methods.name().call({
  from: ‘ownerAddress’ });
```

Comment: The problem is solved. I used one bracket to much in the abi...